# Create custom fields for Interface from Returned Response

Tags: typescript, spfx

The web service I am calling from my SPFX web part has properties beginning with a number: 30DaysTotal, 60DaysTotal and 90DaysTotal.

I have created an Interface to implement this:

```
export interface ISummary {
    Id : number;
    "30DaysGrandTotal": number;
    "60DaysGrandTotal": number;
    "90DaysGrandTotal": number;
}
```

After some research I found if I add the speech marks around the variable then its accepted.

I am then using the following standard out of the box to read the values:

```
this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
      .getClient('('*********************',')
      .then((client: AadHttpClient): void => {
        client
          .get('*********************', AadHttpClient.configurations.v1)
          .then((response: HttpClientResponse): Promise<ISummary> => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((summary: ISummary): void => {

            console.log(summary);
            
             let summaryList: string='';

            summaryList = `
              <li>${summary.Id}</li>
              <li>${summary.30DaysGrandTotal}</li>
              <li>${summary.60DaysGrandTotal}</li>
              <li>${summary.90DaysGrandTotal}</li>              
             `;

            this.summaryDetailsElement.innerHTML = `
              <div name="summary" id="summary"><ul>${summaryList}</ul></div>`;
          });
      });
```

I cannot build the solution as it complains of the variables with the following error:

```
[16:42:03] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/aadHttpClient/AadHttpClientWebPart.ts(189,28): error TS1005: '}' expected.
[16:42:03] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/aadHttpClient/AadHttpClientWebPart.ts(189,31): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[16:42:03] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/aadHttpClient/AadHttpClientWebPart.ts(189,46): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[16:42:03] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/aadHttpClient/AadHttpClientWebPart.ts(189,47): error TS1110: Type expected.
[16:42:03] Error - [tsc] src/webparts/aadHttpClient/AadHttpClientWebPart.ts(189,48): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.
```

If I comment out the 3 lines with the variables the code builds and I can see the summary Class in the console log with the values.

My question is what do I need to change for the variables to allow the code to build?

Answer (score 0):

I just couldn't see it, so simple :)

```
<li>${summary["30DaysGrandTotal"]}</li>
```